# When the pullback functor is monadic

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory, functors, pullback

Consider a site $(\mathcal C,J)$ and the category of sheaves $\mathscr S=\mbox{Sh}(\mathcal C,J)$ on it. Given a morphism $f:X\rightarrow Y$ between sheaves, when is the [pullback funtor](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/base+change) $f^*:\mathscr S/Y\rightarrow\mathscr S/X$ [monadic](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monadic+functor)? And what if I consider sheaves valued in a generic complete category $\mathcal A$ (instead of $\mathbf{Set}$)?

Comment: The category of sheaves is Barr-exact, so the pullback functor is monadic iff $f$ is a regular epimorphism.

Comment: And is this still true with sheaves taking values in a arbitrary complete category?

Comment: In some categories it would definitely fail. I'm pretty sure it would not be true for $\mathcal{A}=\mathbf{Top}$ for example.

Comment: great, thank you!